# Access to Guzzle proxy headers during HTTPS

Tags: php, https, proxy, header, guzzle

I am in the process of writing Guzzle middleware (version 6.2.1) to allow proxy sticky sessions for outbound HTTP requests. For example, the first access to a pool of proxy servers returns a proxy node ID header. Using this header value in subsequent requests will ensure that the same node continues to be used.

Here is my problem: When using HTTPS, the proxy node ID header is contained within an initial proxy connection header. I can't seem to access this in Guzzle no matter what I try. Here is a typical transaction run under PHP native libcurl-based Curl:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
Proxy-Node-ID: 12345

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2016 00:06:04 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: NID=87=VP_ptZU47mOXvC10uU2Ue6UVpLi8p9ngovbLfViChxGjEupGx3UKh4QXi2dyU0QqBSwfgkR9nxgJGLQdnAm2adKWsAGvdzZCCwgC1kqJpc0ZE9BNaqT_FapqULWGitx0ZNQJpJfJYZIasQ; expires=Tue, 04-Apr-2017 00:06:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The header I need is in that first proxy "Connection established" section, "Proxy-Node-ID". I can access all of these headers pretty easily with PHP's native curl implementation. But sadly, PHP's native Libcurl backed curl lacks the powerful middleware capabilities of Guzzle that I really need.

Here is a minimal example. To keep code the code short, I am leaving out the middleware I have written. (I'm sorry that I can't provide a working proxy user/pass):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;

$handler = new CurlHandler();
$stack = HandlerStack::create($handler);
$url = 'https://www.google.com/';

// Select proxy:
$proxy = 'http://'.'someuser:somepass' .'@'.'someproxy.com:12345';

// Instantiate client with options:
$client = new Client(['handler' => $stack,
                      'proxy' => $proxy,]);

$response = $client->request('GET', $url);

$responseHeaders = $response->getHeaders();

foreach ($responseHeaders as $key => $values) {
    $responseHeaders[$key] = implode(', ', $values);
}
var_dump($responseHeaders);
```

Header response from above code:

```
array(13) {
  ["Date"]=>
  string(29) "Mon, 03 Oct 2016 01:35:55 GMT"
  ["Expires"]=>
  string(2) "-1"
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(18) "private, max-age=0"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(29) "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  ["P3P"]=>
  string(109) "CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info.""
  ["Server"]=>
  string(3) "gws"
  ["X-XSS-Protection"]=>
  string(13) "1; mode=block"
  ["X-Frame-Options"]=>
  string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
  ["Set-Cookie"]=>
  string(214) "NID=87=ATOuQjSf6g_95LdzKPjeec1NGABDjgysBZF35AEwNK1YSGWe5nbvFot1Ju_f_H1vL2FAPYK26HhWWqePDfL2XlBxBUpMd0yDbqEdH6nST1qqesGl3nV-Hp1CTcLg_YhB; expires=Tue, 04-Apr-2017 01:35:55 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk; HttpOnly"
  ["Alt-Svc"]=>
  string(43) "quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32""
  ["Accept-Ranges"]=>
  string(4) "none"
  ["Vary"]=>
  string(15) "Accept-Encoding"
  ["Transfer-Encoding"]=>
  string(7) "chunked"
}
```

As you can see, the initial "200 Connection Established" message and the "Proxy-Node-ID" header are missing completely. I need to find some way to access this header.

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never I guess.
Took me hours to get this to work.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/';
// Select proxy:
$proxy = 'http://'.'someuser:somepass' .'@'.'someproxy.com:12345';$headers = [];
$guzzleClient = new Client();
$options = [
  'proxy' => $proxy,    
  \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ON_HEADERS => function (ResponseInterface $response) use (&$headers) {
                   $headers = array_merge($headers, $response->getHeaders());
         }
    ];        
$response = $guzzleClient->get($url, $options);
```